# how to access global variables from parse modules?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have the **main.js** file in the parse cloud, where I import an util module

```
var util = require('cloud/util.js');
```

Now, I have another module, called user

```
var user = require('cloud/user.js');
```

The problem is that if I want to use the util var inside the user, it will say:

```
Failed with: ReferenceError: util is not defined
```

Comment: `util` should have the scope it was declared within; if `user` is in another (non-shared) scope, it will be undefined. In this context is how we will know what going is on, and it's not shown in your question. For instance, if it's something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/24eqarmr/1).

Comment: Not sure what parse uses behind the scenes.. they have one entry point called main.js where I declare those vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the require is more like an import so if you want to use util inside the user.js file, you simply need to add a new

`var util = require('cloud/util.js');`